# Eigenvalues / vectors of $PQP$, where $P, Q$ are both orthogonal projections

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any good way to characterize the eigenvalues / eigenvectors of $PQP$, where $P, Q$ are both orthogonal projection matrices? There are trivial cases when the spaces onto which $P,Q$ project are either orthogonal (in which case the $PQP = 0$) or when $\mathcal{C}(P) = A + B$, $\mathcal{C}(Q) = A + C$, $B\perp C$ (in which case the $PQP$ becomes a projection onto $A$). However, in general, $PQP$ may not even be a projection matrix. Can we still characterize its eigenvalues / vectors? Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Obviously, since $0\le PQP\le 1$, the eigenvalues are in $[0,1]$, and this is all one can say as you can confirm by considering rank one projections $P=ee^*$, $Q=ff^*$.

Comment: Well, I think you can say that the eigenvectors are all eigenvectors of P...

Comment: For anyone who comes after me, there is a characterization of the spectrum of $PQP$ in terms of the principal angles between the subspaces onto which $P, Q$ are projecting. It appears as Proposition 2 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.06535